# Commit after opening cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle

Can anybody suggest, whether we should use commit after opening and before closing cursor?

Comment: In what context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If i have a cursor for loop and using commit inside, what can be cons/prons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is irrelevant in most cases.

A cursor is a construct for retrieving data.  Once the records have been read it doesn't matter when in the process the cursor is closed, providing it is closed.

The COMMIT should be issued when the transaction is complete and not before.

The one case when the order of these two actions matters is when we are executing a CURSOR FOR loop.  It is very important that any COMMIT should occur outside of this loop, that is before we open the cursor or after we close it.   Otherwise we can have problems with read consistency.   There are people who will argue that they have to commit inside the loop for some complicated reasons, but they are almost always mistaken.

The importance of this last case should not be overestimated.  Most transactions should use SQL rather than DML inside a PL/SQL cursor, so it rarely applies.

Comment: +1 for explanation on both the right time to use commit as well as avoiding the "dreaded" incremental commit.

Comment: Do you mean "read consistency problems" as "Snapshot too old" problems or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If the cursor locks records using FOR UPDATE, then all locks will be released by the commit.  (In fact, any locks held are released by the commit.)

Also, you are more likely to get an "ORA-01555 Snapshot too old" error due to the "fetch across commit" - see [this AskTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:546822742166).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Sometimes you want to do that, sometimes you don't. Can you specify what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your approach, for example in Pragma autonomous transaction could be desirable at the end of "entire" transaction to avoid partial information recorded , but when you need read another transaction in the same process and "release" info as fast as possible, you could make it with COMMIT. regards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).